# How to destroy an instance of CountdownTimer?

Tags: android, kotlin, countdowntimer

I am needing to destroy an instance of a CountdownTimer in my code. I have tried `timer.cancel()` but this just pauses the timer. I don't see a `timer.destroy()` or anything similar.

Here is how my timer is instantiated:

```
timer = object : CountDownTimer(COUNTDOWN_TIME, ONE_SECOND - 500) {

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                    currentTime?.let {
                            _currentTime.value = millisUntilFinished / ONE_SECOND
                    }
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                _currentTime.value = DONE          
            }
        }

timer.start()
```

The _currentTime is a LiveData object to keep track of time across fragments.

Comment: is this timer call by activity or fragment? is possible activity/fragment state to background and recreate another instance so background timer still run?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to cancel the `countdowntimer`. [Countdowntimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer) has four methods

- cancel()
- onFinish()
- onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
- start()

if you want to destroy the instance just assign the null value to the variable. But it's not the recommended approach.

Comment: You might want to point out that setting the reference to "null" does not stop the timer, since it holds a reference on itself until it is finished. `cancel()` will do fine.

Comment: @greeble31 Yes, after `cancel()` if he wants to destroy the object. Then I will suggest assigning null to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
resetButton.setOnClickListener {
  timer.onFinish()
}
```

or

```
override fun onFinish() {
  timer.onFinish()
}
```